# Pivot tables in laravel: how do I access more than just the ids?

Tags: laravel, pivot

I'm working on my first project in laravel 5.1, a family tree.  For home movies, I have a videos table and a people table, and I have person_video pivot table to keep track of what people appear in each video. That table also has a description column, for hints like '0:29-0:35, toward the front, wearing a hat'.

Video.php has:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'person_video');
}
```

Then when I display the people who are in a given video, I have:

```
@foreach($video->people as $person)
    @include ('person.partials._person_link', ['person' => $person]):
    {{$person->pivot}} 
@endforeach
```

The info displays for the people, but for pivot it only gives me values for video_id and person_id:

```
 {"video_id":6,"person_id":4}
```

It doesn't include the description (or the timestamps either, not that I need that here).  How can I have the description come along for the ride?  I'd like to be able to use {{$person->pivot->description}}, but when I try that there's nothing to show for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [LaravelDocs/Eloquent/Working with pivot tables](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables):

> By default, only the keys will be present on the `pivot` object. If your
>   pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when
>   defining the relationship:
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
> ```
>
> Now the `foo` and `bar` attributes will be accessible on our `pivot` object for the `Role` model.

So your `Video::people()` would look like this:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'person_video')->withPivot('description');
}
```

Then you should be able to access `{{$person->pivot->description}}` from your view.